# Move many Images by click on forward / backward button in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiimage, slideshow

Thank you Luke Patterson, your answer has helped me so much!

Additional i have another question, how can i stop at last/first image?

my code is:

```
import UIKit




class ViewController: UIViewController {

let images = ["con-el-1.png","con-el-2.png","con-el-3.png"]
var index:Int = 0
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


@IBAction func buttonUp(sender: AnyObject) {

    if(index < images.count){
        index = index + 1

        let img = UIImage(named: images[index])
        imageView.image = img

    }
}




@IBAction func buttonDown(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (index >= 0) {
        index = index - 1

        let img = UIImage(named: images[index])
        imageView.image = img
    }
}
```

Comment: How about PageViewController and then changing the pageViewController's viewController on button tap ???

Comment: You can use for that UIScollView + UIPageControl

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one UIImageView and switch the pictures on it.
You can have the default image be your first image and then follow the code below:

on forward button press

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName2.png")
```

on back button press

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "imageName1.png")
```

For more than two images you can place those images in an array of UIImages and then switch through them using the buttons like so:

```
let images:[UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.png"),UIImage(named: "image2.png"),UIImage(named: "image3.png")]
var index:Int = 0
```

then on forward button press

```
if(index < images.count){
    index = index + 1
    imageView.image = images[index]
}
```

and on back button press

```
if(index >= 0){
    index = index - 1
    imageView.image = images[index]
}
```

The if statements ensure that you are switching between images that exist in the array

Comment: how to stop at the last image or first image?

Comment: disable the button when index = 0 or index = images.count